# Facebook: Notes for publish_actions says Apps won't be approve for this use of publish_actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to submit a `publish_actions` to will enable users of my site request for publish actions so that my site can automatically post to their wall when they post an update on my site. I have filled the form and have added all other details but when I click option 3 in the options below I get this:

**Apps won't be approved for this use of publish_actions. To be approved, apps must follow our review criteria and the guidelines for using publish_actions.**

These are the Facebook options when I click on **Add Notes**:

1. Lets people post to Facebook using a custom composer
2. Publishes Open Graph stories
3. Publishes content to Facebook automatically
4. Lets people publish to Facebook using the Share dialog or Feed dialog.

Can **1** and **2** do what I want? If no, how do I make it possible for my site to post automatically?

Comment: No, you can not automatically post to user’s walls. Users should trigger each single post individually.

Comment: @CBroe: How do I make it post automatically?

Comment: You don’t, because you are not supposed to do that. Again: Your users should actively decide to make a post each and every time. So the easiest thing to do would be to just use the Share or the Feed dialog, so that they can share a link to their update on your site when they decide they want to. (And using those dialogs would not even need any permissions.)

Comment: @CBroe: I have a check box that can be checked or unchecked to grant or revoke posting to Facebook automatically. Twitter has this feature on. I want similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Facebook docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill
- https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control